# How can I play an audio stream from a BLOB from an external server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, blob, android-mediaplayer

In my application I have sent an audio 3gp file to the server and then using PHP I have stored it in a MySQL database as a BLOB. Is there a way to use a MediaPlayer in android to play an audio stream that is read directly from a BLOB? I know that I could read a BLOB and save it in a filesystem and then play it in android without downloading it but I would like to do not save any files in the server if possible. Thanks for the advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that MediaPlayer will let you feed it a URL, you could stream it via a PHP script that fetches the BLOB and echoes it to the output all without ever saving it to the filesystem or Android device. If your PHP script supports HTTP `Range` responses, you could even support seeking.

The script **smartReadFile.php** is a PHP script for streaming files with respect to `Range` requests.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jplayer/nSM2UmnSKKA/bC-l3k0pCPMJ

Comment: That sounds very promising! Just to confirm if I understood well I can use mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL with smartReadFile.php) ,is that correct?

Comment: smartReadFile function can accept 3 paramters: $location, $filename and $mimeType What should I pass then into $location and $filename if my file is in MySQL BLOB?

Comment: You will need to modify smartReadFile() so it queries your database instead of reading a specific file. You don't really have a $filename, but you could make something up or probably omit it. $mimeType should match your content's MIME type.

Comment: I have a hard time to modify this function to query a db instead of reading a file. However I will check your answer as an accepted since the idea of accomplish this problem is good. Do you have any propositions of how to change this function to query db? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try the sample following code: try to change according to your requirement, this code only reads the file from BLOB :

```
                   SQLiteDatabase myDb;       
               String MySQL;
               byte[] byteImage1 = null; 
               byte[] byteImage2 = null;
               MySQL="create table emp1(_id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, sample TEXT not null, picture BLOB);";
               myDb = openOrCreateDatabase("Blob List", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
               myDb.execSQL(MySQL);
               String s=myDb.getPath();
               textView.append("\r\n" + s+"\r\n");       
               myDb.execSQL("delete from emp1");
               ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
               newValues.put("sample", "HI Hello");


            try
            {
            FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/AudioRecorder/AudioRecorder.wav"); 
            BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream); 
            byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()]; 
            bif.read(byteImage1); 
            textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage1.length+"\r\n"); 
            newValues.put("picture", byteImage1); 

            long ret = myDb.insert("emp1", null, newValues); 
            if(ret<0) textView.append("\r\n!!! Error add blob filed!!!\r\n");
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                textView.append("\r\n!!! Error: " + e+"!!!\r\n");   
            }


            Cursor cur = myDb.query("emp1",null, null, null, null, null, null);
            cur.moveToFirst();
            while (cur.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
                textView.append("\r\n" + cur.getString(1)+"\r\n");
                cur.moveToNext();
            }
        ///////Read data from blob field////////////////////
            cur.moveToFirst();
            byteImage2=cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("picture")); 
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0, byteImage2.length));
            textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage2.length+"\r\n"); 

            cur.close();

            myDb.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however I can't use it in my case. I don't store the file in a file system but as a BLOB in an external database, not SQLite